# Using Variable as part of column name in Dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

I am trying to use a variable as part of a column name in a dynamic SQL statement.

I have 4 columns that are called `Player1Action`, `Player2Action`, `Player3Action` and `Player4Action`.

Depending on the varaible `@CurrentPlayerId`, I want to update the relevant player column with some data.

So for example, if CurrentPlayerId contains `1`, then update column `Player1Action`.

I realise I could achieve this with a series of IF statements, but I would like to do it in a cleaner manner.

I have the following code, but I think my escaping is causing issues. I have re-written this a view times but I don't seem to be able to get it to work.

```
DECLARE
@CurrentPlayerId INT,
@CurrentPlayerBetAmount nvarchar(MAX),
@stmt nvarchar(MAX);

SET @CurrentPlayerId = 1
SET @CurrentPlayerBetAmount = 100

SET @stmt = N'UPDATE HandCurrent SET ''Player'' ''+'' @CurrentPlayerId ''+'' ''Action'' = 1 '','' ''Player'' ''+'' @CurrentPlayerId ''+'' ''ActionSize'' = @CurrentPlayerBetAmount'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @stmt
```

If I run this as a select I get the following returned.

```
UPDATE HandCurrent SET 'Player' '+' @CurrentPlayerId '+' 'Action' = 1 ',' 'Player' '+' @CurrentPlayerId '+' 'ActionSize' = @CurrentPlayerBetAmount
```

Comment: Please tag question with RDBMS you're using

Comment: why dont do `SELECT @stmt`  to see the result sql ?

Comment: @Kacper done, thanks!

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I have tried doing that, but the result doesn't really explain to me which its going wrong. I can post the output of the select if that helps?

Comment: please do, that help to see the problem

Comment: Far cleaner would be to fix your schema (fewer columns, more rows), so that 1-4 are appearing as *data* rather than embedded in column names and so that a single column stores all actions (one action per row)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, this table has a single row and is constantly updated as the contents are read by C# application. I have a secondary table that recieves the same information and stores it row by row as a history of what has happened!

Comment: Output of select, added to the question. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DECLARE
@CurrentPlayerId INT,
@CurrentPlayerBetAmount INT,
@stmt nvarchar(MAX);

SET @CurrentPlayerId = 1
SET @CurrentPlayerBetAmount = 100

SET @stmt = N'UPDATE HandCurrent SET 
            Player' + CAST(@CurrentPlayerId AS NVARCHAR(10)) + 'Action = 1, 
            Player' + CAST(@CurrentPlayerId AS NVARCHAR(10)) + 'ActionSize = ' 
           + CAST(@CurrentPlayerBetAmount AS NVARCHAR(10))

EXECUTE sp_executesql @stmt
```

Juan Carlos had it right only issue is datatypes of variables `@CurrentPlayerId` is an INT so you would need to cast it to `NVARCHAR()` https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3014/concatenation-of-different-sql-server-data-types/.

To be consistent you should have declared `@CurrentPlayerBetAmount` as `INT` as well.  If you do then you need to cast it too.

However, you could also simply DECLARE both as `NVARCAHR(MAX)` and then single quote the value when setting it such as:

```
DECLARE
@CurrentPlayerId NVARCHAR(MAX),
@CurrentPlayerBetAmount NVARCHAR(MAX),
@stmt nvarchar(MAX);

SET @CurrentPlayerId = '1'
SET @CurrentPlayerBetAmount = '100'

SET @stmt = N'UPDATE HandCurrent SET 
            Player' + @CurrentPlayerId + 'Action = 1, 
            Player' + @CurrentPlayerId + 'ActionSize = ' + @CurrentPlayerBetAmount

EXECUTE sp_executesql @stmt
```

Or My preference if you are going to change a record anyway would be just to do the update statement if you have 4 columns.  You could also think of nth Normalizing and making the columns Rows....

```
DECLARE @CurrentPlayerId INT = 1
DECLARE @CurrentPlayerBetAmount INT = 100

UPDATE HandCurrent
    Player1Action = CASE WHEN @CurrentPlayerId = 1 THEN 1 ELSE PlayerAction1 END
    ,Player1ActionSize = CASE WHEN @CurrentPlayerId = 1 THEN @CurrentPlayerBetAmount ELSE Player1ActionSize END
    ,Player2Action = CASE WHEN @CurrentPlayerId = 2 THEN 1 ELSE PlayerAction2 END
    ,Player2ActionSize = CASE WHEN @CurrentPlayerId = 2 THEN @CurrentPlayerBetAmount ELSE Player2ActionSize END
    ,Player3Action = CASE WHEN @CurrentPlayerId = 3 THEN 1 ELSE PlayerAction3 END
    ,Player3ActionSize = CASE WHEN @CurrentPlayerId = 3 THEN @CurrentPlayerBetAmount ELSE Player3ActionSize END
    ,Player4Action = CASE WHEN @CurrentPlayerId = 4 THEN 1 ELSE PlayerAction4 END
    ,Player4ActionSize = CASE WHEN @CurrentPlayerId = 4 THEN @CurrentPlayerBetAmount ELSE Player4ActionSize END
WHERE
    ????
```

Note you are actually updating the entire table is that what you desire?

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

dont quote the variables.

```
SET @stmt = N'UPDATE HandCurrent SET 
            Player' + @CurrentPlayerId + 'Action = 1, 
            Player' + @CurrentPlayerId + 'ActionSize = ' + @CurrentPlayerBetAmount
```

Comment: Don't quote the operators either. OP had them double single quotes.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, this doesnt work for me, as it seems to show a qoute is missing.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza now its complaining about a conversion error.

"Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'UPDATE HandCurrent SET 
            Player' to data type int."

Comment: `Player1ActionSize` is string?

Comment: @CurrentPlayerId is an INT and would need to be cast to NVARCHAR()...https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3014/concatenation-of-different-sql-server-data-types/ o change variable to nvarchar instead of INT.  Which is how CurrentPlayerBetAmount is

Answer (score 0):

Speaking of cleanest way to do this, IMHO the best approach is to use `sp_executesql` with parameters, implying the `@CurrentPlayerId` and `@CurrentPlayerBetAmount` are input parameters of the given code:

```
Declare @sql nvarchar(256)
    , @sql1 nvarchar(256) = N'update HandCurrent
    Set Player1Action =@value,
    Player1ActionSize =@size'
    , @sql2 nvarchar(256) = N'update HandCurrent
    Set Player2Action =@value,
    Player2ActionSize =@size'
    , @params nvarchar (128)
    , @CurrentPlayerId int
    ;

Select @sql = case @CurrentPlayerId when 1 then @sql1 when 2 then @sql2 else '' end;
If @sql <> '' begin
  set @params = N'@value int, @size int';
  execute sp_executesql @sql, @params,
        @value =1,
        @size = @CurrentPlayerBetAmount
        ;
End
```

Comment: While I agree with the paraemterizing dynamic sql when you can the issue is that the parameter is being used to dynamically identify the column names to be updated.  So that wouldn't work for this case, but it would work for the BetAmount as that could be parameterized

Comment: in this particular case yes, but if the `@CurrentPlayerId` is an input parameter, then there are can be much more logic in a UDF that depends on it. In this case we can assign value to `@sql` and do another actions